# Can't add/modify tags on StackOverflow

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags

Running Chrome 14.0.835.186 m. Make edit, save edit, and then it decides it doesn't like me and doesn't show up.

Comment: That's a really detailed and clear bug report.

Comment: Edits on your own question? Someone else's? Tried refreshing? Did you edit just the tags, or body/title too? Do the tags you're trying to add exist? What is *it*? Who are you? What does this butto

Comment: Does your tag already exist? If not, you need to wait until you have [1500 rep](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags) to create a new tag.

Comment: Are you talking about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571262/what-is-the-difference-between-the-calculate-method-and-refreshentireworksheet? What tag were you trying to add?

Comment: There was probably an image involved. Or a shaved donkey.

Answer (score 4):

Without more information, I can only guess what you're trying to do, but...

With only 10 reputation, you can only suggest edits to other people's posts. They have to be approved by two other people before they show up on the site for everyone.

On your own posts, you can edit them already, but you have to have 1500 reputation to be able to create new tags if a tag you want doesn't already exist in the system.